# How do you avoid losing the new content you add in a function

Tags: javascript, forms, appendchild, submission

I am trying to print new information at the end of a div tag. However, since I use a function, the information only appears for a couple of milliseconds before disappearing completely. How can I permanently append new information to a tag in a function?

Javascript code:

```
    function checkSubmission()
{
    var aForm = document.getElementById("frm");
    aForm.addEventListener("submit", displayResultsForm);
}
function displayResultsForm()
{
    var bk1 = document.getElementById("book_1").value;
    var bk2 = document.getElementById("book_2").value;
    var bk3 = document.getElementById("book_3").value;
    if(bk1 == null || bk1 == "" ||  isNaN(bk1) || bk2 == null || bk2 == "" || isNaN(bk2) || bk3 == null || bk3 == "" || isNaN(bk3))
        alert("Error! One of the 3 fields was left empty or does not contain a number.");

    var price1 = (19.99 * bk1).toFixed(2);
    var price2 = (86.00 * bk2).toFixed(2);
    var price3 = (55.00 * bk3).toFixed(2);

    var cont = document.getElementById("container");
    var displayBk1 = "<strong>Basic XHTML (Quantity = " + bk1 + "): $" + price1 + "</strong><br/>";
    var displayBk2 = "<strong>Basic XHTML (Quantity = " + bk2 + "): $" + price2 + "</strong><br/>";
    var displayBk3 = "<strong>Basic XHTML (Quantity = " + bk3 + "): $" + price3 + "</strong><br/>";

    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode(displayBk1 + displayBk2 + displayBk3);
    para.appendChild(node);
    cont.appendChild(para);
}
window.addEventListener( "load", checkSubmission, false );
```

part of the HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <h2>Order Books Online</h2>
    <form action="" method="post" id="frm">
```

Thank you all so much in advance!!

Comment: That is not _"since I use a function"_ but simply due to the fact that the form is submitted. So go research how to prevent that.

Comment: I added this at the beginning:

function displayResultsForm(event)
{
 event.preventDefault();
[...]

And now it works!
It is because as you said, when the form is submitted, the display goes back to the default one, ignoring any modifications done in the js file right?